# How to obtain price correctly from string

Tags: python, regex

**Set-up**

I'm web scraping product prices using Selenium and Python 3.x.

I have a list of strings which contain the price of each product.

For prices below €1000, the strings look like `'€ 505.93 net'` (i.e. `505.93`).
For prices from €1000, the strings look like `'€ 1 505.93 net'` (i.e. `1505.93`).

---

**Problem**

I'm not sure how to neatly deal with the space in the thousand prices and the dot.

Let `product_price = '€ 1 505.93 net'`, then,

```
[int(s) for s in product_price if s.isdigit()]
```

gives,

```
[1, 5, 0, 5, 9, 3]
```

Analogous procedure on `product_price = '€ 505.93 net'` gives `[5, 0, 5, 9, 3]`.

---

**Question**

How do adjust my code such that I get `1505.93` and `505.93`?

Comment: Do you also need to deal with `,` vs. `.` (depending on region)? Or are the format requirements fixed?

Comment: It's all `.` as far as I can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach.  We can match on the following regex pattern, which uses space as the thousands separator:

```
€\s*(\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Then, the first capture group should contain the matching Euro amounts.

```
input = '€ 1 505.93 net and here is another price € 505.93'
result = re.findall(r'€\s*(\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*\.\d+)', input)
print list(result)

['1 505.93', '505.93']
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
€                  a Euro sign
\s*                followed by optional whitespace
(                  (capture what follows)
    \d{1,3}        one to three digits
    (?: \d{3})*    followed by zero or more thousands groups
    (?:\.\d+)?     an optional decimal component
)                  (close capture group)
```

Comment: [x.replace(' ','') for x in re.findall(r'€\s*(\d+(?: \d{3})*\.\d+)', input)]    If you want to remove spaces

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regular expression for this:

```
import re
pattern = r'((?:\d\s)?\d+\.\d+)'
re.findall(pattern, '€ 1 505.93 and € 505.93')
>>['1 505.93', '505.93']
```

Explanation:

- `\d` represents at digit

  `\s` represents a space

  `?:` notation is a non capturing group notation

  `?` to specify optional groups

So

```
(?:\d\s)?
```

The number followed by space shouldn't be captured alone and this pattern is optional

`\d+.\d+`
 specifies a floating point number

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would be best off using regular expressions. Also, your question specified the following output as a float, not a string, so I added a conversion to float after joining the output of the regex.

```
import re

def bar(string):
    return float(''.join(re.findall(r"[\d.]", string)))

a = '€ 1 505.93 net'
b = '€ 505.93 net'

print(bar(a))
print(bar(b))
```

Output:

```
1505.93
505.93
```

If you also want to handle commas, for regional compatibility, you can use replace() to swap it for a period:

```
def bar(string):
    return float(''.join(re.findall(r"[\d.,]", string)).replace(',', '.'))

c = '€ 6 812,51 net'
print(bar(c))
```

Output:

```
6812.51
```